# Change GridLayout in Java from horizontal to vertical with event.

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener, grid-layout

I have a project im working on. Im trying to change the flag layouts from horizontal to vertical on the button press. Ive added a line of code to change the grid layout under the if "Bulgaria" statement, but it doesnt work.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Flags extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    Container pane;
    JPanel display,displayCenter,displayBottom,displayTop,buttonArea;
    JButton Flag1,Flag2,Flag3,Flag4,Flag5,Flag6;
    public Flags () {
        setSize(600, 500);
        setTitle("Flags");
        setLocation(150, 150);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pane = getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        display = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,0));
        displayTop=new JPanel();
        display.add(displayTop);
        displayCenter=new JPanel();
        display.add(displayCenter);
        displayBottom=new JPanel();
        display.add(displayBottom);
        pane.add(display, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        Flag1 = new JButton ("Argentina");
        Flag1.addActionListener(this);
        Flag2 = new JButton ("Armenia");
        Flag2.addActionListener(this);
        Flag3 = new JButton ("Austria");
        Flag3.addActionListener(this);
        Flag4 = new JButton ("Azerbaijan");
        Flag4.addActionListener(this);
        Flag5 = new JButton ("Bolivia");
        Flag5.addActionListener(this);
        Flag6 = new JButton ("Bulgaria");
        Flag6.addActionListener(this);
        buttonArea = new JPanel();
        buttonArea.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        buttonArea.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        buttonArea.add(Flag1);
        buttonArea.add(Flag2);
        buttonArea.add(Flag3);
        buttonArea.add(Flag4);
        buttonArea.add(Flag5);
        buttonArea.add(Flag6);
        pane.add(buttonArea, BorderLayout.SOUTH); 
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        if (command.equals("Argentina")){
            displayTop.setBackground(new Color(155,242,242));
            displayCenter.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            displayBottom.setBackground(new Color(155,242,242));
        }
        if (command.equals("Armenia")){
            displayTop.setBackground(Color.RED);
            displayCenter.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            displayBottom.setBackground(new Color(232,152,5));
        }
        if (command.equals("Austria")){
            displayTop.setBackground(Color.RED);
            displayCenter.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            displayBottom.setBackground(Color.RED);
        }
        if (command.equals("Azerbaijan")){
            displayTop.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            displayCenter.setBackground(new Color(232,84,5));
            displayBottom.setBackground(new Color(18,179,18));
        }
        if (command.equals("Bolivia")){
            displayTop.setBackground(Color.RED);
            displayCenter.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            displayBottom.setBackground(new Color(21,179,21));
        }
        if (command.equals("Bulgaria")){
            display = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,3));
            displayTop.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            displayCenter.setBackground(new Color(19,138,19));
            displayBottom.setBackground(Color.RED);
        }
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Flags demo = new Flags();
        demo.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
    ...
    if (command.equals("Bulgaria")){
        displayTop.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        displayCenter.setBackground(new Color(19,138,19));
        displayBottom.setBackground(Color.RED);
        display.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
    }
    else {
        display.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
    }
    display.doLayout();
```

}

Explanation:

You were actually setting a new value to the `display` variable, but this has no effect, since the `JPanel` it used to refer had already been added to `pane`. Moreover, you were setting the background colors of `displayTop`, `displayCenter`, and `displayBottom` all of which had already been added to `display`, so you where actually modifying those `JPanel`s that were already displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you should use:

```
        display.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,3));
        display.revalidate();
```

Longer answer.

First, in you original code, when you call:

```
display = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,3));
```

you create a new panel (with no children), and that is not added to the frame, so basically nothing happens. What you want to do is change the layout of the existing panel (that is added to the frame and has 3 children).

Second, you then have to call "revalidate" to tell swing that you want it to redo the layout.

Third, you will have to set the layout back to the "3,0" case for other flags. I'd recommend you refactor the code to make it simpler and more readable. You could use a method for the flag taking the orientation and the 3 colors. You can also use a switch/case (java 7):

```
private void flag(boolean hor, Color c1, Color c2, Color c3) {
    displayTop.setBackground(c1);
    displayCenter.setBackground(c2);
    displayBottom.setBackground(c3);
    display.setLayout(new GridLayout(hor ? 0 : 3, hor ? 3 : 0));
    display.revalidate();
}
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
    switch (e.getActionCommand()) {
        case "Argentina":
            flag(false, new Color(155,242,242), Color.WHITE, new Color(155,242,242));
            break;
        // ...
        case "Bulgaria":
            flag(true, Color.WHITE, new Color(19,138,19), Color.RED);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thanks just started using the gui in java... this helped so much.

Comment: Also what does the "?" mean?   
    display.setLayout(new GridLayout(hor ? 0 : 3, hor ? 3 : 0));

Comment: The ? is an inline if. "hor ? 0 : 3" has a value of 0 if hor is true and a value of 3 if hor is false. You might as well use a "if/else" and duplicate the setLayout line.

Comment: Ok thanks, I havent learned about the "?", so when you set that up (new GridLayout(hor ? 0 : 3, hor ? 3 : 0)) .... you always put the true statement first?

Comment: yes exactly, see http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018 for more examples and details